# Bootstrapping mixed effect regression coefficients in statsmodels

Tags: mixed-model, python, statsmodels

I have a mixed effect model that looks like this:

```py
import statsmodels.formula.api as smf

formula = "revised_error ~ C(condition, Treatment('solo_feedback'))*round_index"

model = smf.mixedlm(forumla, data=data, groups=data['player_id']).fit()
```

Now `model.conf_int()` gets me the confidence interval for the fitted parameters based on the standard normal distribution. However, I want the bootstrapped coefficients and confidence but `model.boostrap()` throws an error:

```
AttributeError: 'MixedLMResults' object has no attribute 'endog'
```

Comment: any update on the issue ? How did you solve this ? Best, Gautier

Answer (score 2):

The generic bootstrap in Statsmodels (what you get when you call the `bootstrap` method) was not written to handle more complicated settings like mixed models.

Applying the non-parametric bootstrap to dependent data is not straightforward, and I'm not even sure if there is a standard way to do it.  The parametric bootstrap would be more straightforward.  Since we now have a `get_distribution` method (added recently for mediation analysis), it would not be that difficult to implement a parametric bootstrap.  But this is not something that is currently available.